# MVC controller should return 400 when validation query string parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, bad-request

Say you have a simple method in a MVC controller...

```
[Route("{id}", Name = "GetById")]
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(SomeType), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), (int)HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string id, bool? includeNonActive = false)
{
    // some stuff
}
```

Is there any way to get MVC to automagically return a HTTP 400 if invalid value (non-boolean) are passed to the `includeNonActive` query string parameter?

```
HTTP GET http://my-server/api/12321312?includeNonActive=thisIsNotABooleanValue
```

Sure, I can accept a string type for 'includeNonActive', use `Boolean.TryParse()` and `return BadRequest("wtf")`, but that looks ugly in Swagger.

Comment: basically if you make the includeNonActive required (aka: remove the optional value) then the request will be muched only if the includeNonActive is a boolean value.

Comment: That's the way it acts now. And I need it to be optional. In the example query above, the value is just ignored without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to get MVC to automagically return a HTTP 400 if invalid value (non-boolean) are passed to the 'includeNonActive' query string parameter?

Sure, you could build an action filter for this.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class EnsureBooleanQueryParameterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public EnsureBooleanQueryParameterAttribute(string parameterName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameterName))
            throw new ArgumentException($"'{nameof(parameterName)}' is required.");
        this.ParameterName = parameterName;
    }

    public string ParameterName { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var attribute = (EnsureBooleanQueryParameterAttribute)filterContext.ActionDescriptor
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnsureBooleanQueryParameterAttribute), true)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        // The attribute exists on the current action method
        if (attribute != null)
        {
            string param = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString[attribute.ParameterName];
            bool result;
            // If the query string value is present and not boolean
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param) && !bool.TryParse(param, out result))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(400, 
                    "Invalid boolean query string value for '{attribute.ParameterName}'.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then use the filter like:

```
[Route("{id}", Name = "GetById")]
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(SomeType), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), (int)HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable)]
[EnsureBooleanQueryParameter("includeNonActive")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string id, bool? includeNonActive = false)
{
    // some stuff
}
```

You could use this as a starting point and add an `Enum` parameter that you can use to specify the data type and a `bool` parameter to indicate whether or not the value is required to exist in the URL.

Comment: I should have specified that I was using MVC.Core, so I had to change few things. But your code got me 90% of the way there. Thanks. I'll include my answer for those that want to see a Core implementation.

Comment: Also, too bad TryParse isn't in an interface class so this could be made generic.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't specify that I was using MVC Core, so I had to change a few things to get it to work for me. Here's my version.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class BooleanQueryStringParameterTypeValidatorAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public BooleanQueryStringParameterTypeValidatorAttribute(string parameterName)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parameterName))
            throw new ArgumentException($"'{nameof(parameterName)}' is required.");
        this.ParameterName = parameterName;
    }

    protected string ParameterName { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if(!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.HasValue)
            return;

        ControllerActionDescriptor actionDescriptor = filterContext.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
        var attribute = actionDescriptor.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(BooleanQueryStringParameterTypeValidatorAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() as BooleanQueryStringParameterTypeValidatorAttribute;

        // The attribute exists on the current action method
        if(attribute != null)
        {
            Dictionary<string, StringValues> queryString = QueryHelpers.ParseNullableQuery(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Value);
            if(queryString != null && queryString.ContainsKey(attribute.ParameterName))
            {
                bool result;
                // If the query string value is present and not boolean
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString[attribute.ParameterName]) && !bool.TryParse(queryString[attribute.ParameterName], out result))
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult($"Invalid boolean query string value for '{attribute.ParameterName}'.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```